# setting default variables with parameter expansion vs if/else test -z

Tags: bash, parameters, optional-parameters, parameter-expansion

So traditionally when I write bash scripts with argument flags I implement default values with a basic test statement like so

```
if [ -z $foo ]
then
    foo=$bar
fi
```

Today I came across more advanced parameter expansions that seem to do the same thing

```
${foo:=$bar}
```

How do these two methods compare? What are their advantages/disadvantages?

edit: fixed some typos pointed out in the comments

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Both are wrong!  `[-z $foo ]` should be `[ -z $foo ]` and `${foo:=bar}` should be `${foo:=$bar}`.

Comment: Apart from the typos, use which ever is easier to read and maintain.  Note there is also `${foo:-$bar}` and `${foo:?}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical idiom is

```
: ${foo:=$bar}
```

as a replacement for

```
if [ -z "$foo" ]
then
    foo=$bar
fi
```

(note the quotes and whitespace!)

In the former, the parameter expansion handles the assignment for an otherwise do-nothing command. It's more concise, but otherwise there's little reason for choosing one over the other. Note that both are supported by POSIX.

Comment: `: ${foo:=$bar}`